# PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I just switched to Android Studio. I face a rendering problem after creating a blank activity. When I go to xml and pick API 19 or below for preview I see this error:

```
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate  : 
      - PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported.
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.iseemedia.trubleshooter.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title :"
        android:id="@+id/ConnectionSpeedTitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Rendering problem]

Can anybody please explain What's the problem and How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing Rendering API to Upper API levels will make this error disappear. But I still don't know the reason of this problem.

[image]